# Occurances of same alphabet in word from text file

Tags: c

I need a `C` program to get the count of words in which double letters are there from the text file

For example:

```
I SEE WHITE CLOUDS IN THE SKY WITH A COOL BREEZE BLOWING ACROSS
```

the above statement from text file should return

```
count = 4
```

since  SEE, COOL, BREEZE and ACROSS allcontains 2 letter.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
const char FILE_NAME[] = "\\code.txt";
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main() {
int             count = 0;
FILE           *in_file;
int             ch;
in_file = fopen(FILE_NAME, "r");
if (in_file == NULL) {
printf("Cannot open %s\n", FILE_NAME);
exit(8);
}
 while (1) {
ch = fgetc(in_file);
if (ch == EOF)
break;
++count;
}
printf("Number of characters in %s is %d\n",
              FILE_NAME, count);
system("pause");
return (0);
}
```

Comment: Show us your effort first. What have you tried? What is not working?

Comment: where is HELLO and BRILLIANT?

Comment: @Naveen i have posted code.i could able to get the word count from the code but not only the same occurance word i mean ACROSS ,BREEZE etc

Comment: @moeCake i have just copy pasted the statement i got it on exampke

Comment: @MikroDel i did not get you

Comment: Santosh Pisipati - if you dont want that you question will be closed again please show the result of you code. Cause now after edit you question is better but not good enough to stay open

Comment: @Naveen - effort is shown now, but not "What is not workin?" part :)

Comment: @Naveen i could able to get the total word count from the code but could not able to get the same occurance word i mean ACROSS ,BREEZE alike etc Example i am getting count as 13 total words,but i need only count 4(ACROSS,BREEZE,SEE,COOL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to track the last char you've read in: Then compare to it, and increment the Counter if they're equal!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const char FILE_NAME[] = "\\code.txt";

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int             count = 0;
  FILE           *in_file;
  int             ch;
  in_file = fopen(FILE_NAME, "r");
  if (in_file == NULL) {
    printf("Cannot open %s\n", FILE_NAME);
    exit(8);
  }
  char lastChar = 0x00;
  while (true) {
    ch = fgetc(in_file);
    if (ch == EOF){
      break;
    }else if(ch == lastChar){
      ++count;
    }
    lastChar = ch;
  }
  printf("Number of characters in %s is %d\n", FILE_NAME, count);
  system("pause");
  return (0);
}
```

Comment: also if i need to print those words name.FOR example count : 4,words = SEE, COOL, BREEZE and ACROSS etc

Comment: @SantoshPisipati That wasn't written in your inital question. If that code solved your previous problem, then please make sure to mark it as accepted. For any enhancements you should first try to solve it by yourself - then open a new question if you stumbled about problems that you can't solve by yourself.

Comment: though the answer is correct just to confirm that i need to get words along with count please